# How to know if the question asker got his query resolved if he doesnt mark it as solved?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes the question ansker just sees the answer, but doesnt bother to reply or to mark an answer as solved.What should be done in that case?

Is there any way to know whether 
 an answer that one has provided has been seen by the question asker or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way we can tell if the answer works for the original poster unless they mark it as solved, or if the community votes on it enough for the system to mark it as answered.

So if you see something that is useful enough for the next person then vote on it!

Comment: Or just read their fantastic [comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/332019/wrong-mv-command/332052?noredirect=1#comment422696_332052). ;)

Comment: Ok. So there's no way to know.

Comment: *One vote* on any answer (assuming it has no downvotes) is enough for the system to consider a question "answered." Voting is good and important, but keeping questions from appearing in the unanswered list is only infrequently a reason to vote.

Comment: **Answered** and **solved** are not the same thing though.

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear enough: how does the question Answerer know that his answer was viewed by the question Asker; because if the question Asker saw the Answer, then he/she would have acted on it, and probably got his/her query "Solved", but if they dont mark it as solved how does the answerer know his effort helped or not?